# RestSharp works on localhost, but returns an error when uploaded to host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, restsharp

I built a website that gets data from an API using RestSharp. I am able to post the data and display it on the website, it works perfect when I run it on Loaclhost. After completing this website, I uploaded it to my hosting online and when I run the page I get this error:

**Server Error** in '/Application' Application.

**Compilation Error Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Source Error:**

Line 1:  using System;

Line 2:  using RestSharp;

Line 3:  using RestSharp.Deserializers;

Line 4:  using RestSharp.Authenticators;

I have tried different solutions posted online but cannot resolve this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to check whatever you upload to hosting online has RestSharp libraries included in it. How have you referred them in the project?

Comment: I uploaded it to my university hosting, and I installed RestSharp through NuGet. I am not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: What do you upload to the hosting? Does it have RestSharp libraries?

Comment: I normally upload .net applications so I am not sure if it does, I will ask the admins to see if the hosting does contain RestSharp libraries. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hosting doesn't have the RestSharp libraries.

You will need to find a new one that does.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn’t upload the dependent assemblies to your host.  Doing a “Publish” from Visual Studio will bundle those assemblies for you and should solve your issues.